# Need SQL query to group together but sort overall

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table with Display_UPC, Brand, Item_Description, and other fields. There are several items with the same Display_UPC (all items belonging to the same display), and some displays have multiple brands.

I'm trying to print out a page that shows all of the Display contents (all Display_UPC together) with the various item descriptions, but sorted by Brand (so it starts with the "A" brands at the top of the page, then "B" brands, etc...).

Problem is, if I try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tbl_All_Displays
ORDER BY Brand, Display_UPC
```

some of the displays (the ones containing multiple brands) are missing some items because they are different brands. I can get rid of "Brand" in the ORDER BY and it returns complete displays together but they are not sorted by Brand (obviously).

I'm guessing maybe a GROUP BY is needed here but I can't get one to work. If I try something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tbl_All_Displays
GROUP BY Display_UPC
ORDER BY Brand, Display_UPC
```

I get the error:

```
Column 'tbl_All_Displays.Item_Description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

But I need Item_Description (and the other various fields) to be displayed on the page. They just aren't important in the ordering/grouping.

Sample Data:

[image: Sample Data]

Sample Expected Result:

[image: Sample Expected Result]

So, basically, it doesn't matter which brand in a display the query uses in the sort. If a display contains a brand then it's okay for it to belong to that brand "group" if that makes sense.  Is this possible?

Note: I deleted and reposted a previos question because it got messy with edits.

Edit: Here is sqlfiddle with sample table data - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5069c

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com and you will get answer

Comment: Okay, I've never used sqlfiddle.com before.  I'll try to get it set up within a few minutes.

Comment: Here is a sample for sql server http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dfcce/3

Comment: Why did you create new question for this? As was suggested twice in your other question all you need to do is change the order by to Display_UPC, Brand

Comment: Your result doesnt make much sense. First a query with row as title with empty columns Is that a requirement for a `SQL` or for a `Report`?  Then how first row say `Gerber` when have item from other brands? and also result include empty lines?

Comment: Sorry, the result doesn't actually need to have the title with empty columns.  That was just me illustrating that the overall result is sorted by Brand (Gerber, Little Tikes, Luvs, Munchkin) and then all the items in each display are together.

Comment: I think this is a set up sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ef57

I did it in mysql but my database is actually sql server.  Don't think it will matter much for the query.

Comment: Then fix the result because right now is very confusing. My answer is just sort because no need for distinct or group by using current sample.

Comment: Simply ordering by Display_UPC, Brand won't work.  You can see here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ef57/3

that if you do that then you get display 22222 listed second in the "display groups" but 22222 doesn't contain a "Gerber" item.  I'd need anything containing Gerber first, then anything containing Little Tikes (ignoring any that were already returned in the Gerber group), etc...

Comment: You tagged `SQL Server`, but your fiddle is `mysql`, what's correct?

Comment: SQL Server is correct.  My import query didn't work for SQL Server on that site so I just switched to MySQL and it worked.  I assume it won't matter for the query I'm looking for but if it does then I'll try to recreate.

Comment: @JackHillard You could try these steps. First set `sql server`, then use `text to ddl` button on the top tool bar.

Comment: Ah, cool, that seemed to work.  Here is the SQL Server version - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5069c

Thanks Juan!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to sort first by the `min(Brand)` of each `Display_UPC`?

Then you need to sort by a "Group Min" first ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5069c/4)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
ORDER BY 
   min(Brand) over (partition by Display_UPC),
   Display_UPC, 
   Brand
```

Comment: This looks like exactly the result I'm looking for!  Can you tell me what "over (partition by Display_UPC)" means?

Comment: Is like you do a `group by` ... similar to this `SELECT Display_UPC, MIN(BRAND)  FROM Table1  GROUP BY Display_UPC`

Comment: It's similar to the result of a GROUP BY, but without removing the detail rows, most DBMSes support those "Windowed Aggregate Functions". For SQL Server see some articles at Simple Talk, e.g.: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

dnoeth did a great solution. But i want show the one I was working with.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5069c/11)**

```
with 
    minBrand as (
       SELECT Display_UPC, MIN(BRAND) Brand
       from Table1
       GROUP BY Display_UPC
    )
select m.Brand MainBrand, t.* 
from minBrand  m
inner join Table1 t    
   on m.Display_UPC = t.Display_UPC
order by m.Brand, t.Display_UPC, t.Brand, t.Item_Description
```